# Couchbase: how to automatically deserialize linked documents

Tags: serialization, deserialization, couchbase

Okay, so I'm working with Couchbase 2.0 and the most recent .NET client.
Basically what I'm writing is a project to keep track of goals (a glorified to-do list)...

I've managed to store a goal object as a JSON document within couchbase and then deserialize it back into a POCO, but my question is how to automatically lookup the linked documents and populate the subGoal List<Goal>

Not sure if this kind of automatic deserialization is possible without some logic to handle it within the code itself but any pointers appreciated, cheers!

JSON

```
{
    id: "goal_1",
    name: "goal 1",
    description: "think of some better projects",
    subGoals: [goal_2, goal_3]
}
```

C#

```
var goal = client.GetJson<Goal>(id);
return goal;
```

Here's the POCO

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace stuff.Models
{
    public class Goal
    {
        protected DateTime _targetDate;

        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the goal
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Full description of the goal
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public String Description { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Target date for completing this goal
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("targetDate")]
        public DateTime? TargetDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _targetDate;
            }
            set
            {
                // target date must be later than any sub-goal target dates
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Any sub-goals
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("subGoals")]
        public List<Goal> SubGoals { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Name"></param>
        /// <param name="Description"></param>
        /// <param name="TargetDate"></param>
        /// <param name="SubGoals"></param>
        public Goal(String Name, String Description, DateTime? TargetDate = null, List<Goal> SubGoals = null)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Description = Description;
            this.TargetDate = TargetDate;
            this.SubGoals = SubGoals;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Linked documents? The sub goals are not full Goal objects in the original Goal document? They are references to other documents?

Comment: Yeah, in the JSON document I just want to store IDs to related goals but have them deserialize back automatically into the objects themselves

Comment: Ah. I don't know of a way to automatically do that. I believe the document "way" if you will, is to store the entire document in the array, not just the reference. You could write a function in .NET that manually goes through each sub goal, but of course you'd pay the price for each call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no automatic way to get related documents back in one "join" query, however you could use a collated view.  So given a set of goals like below (note the addition of a type property):

```
{"name":"goal 1","description":"This is a parent goal","subgoals":["goal2","goal3"],"type":"goal"}
{"name":"goal 2","description":"This is a child goal","type":"goal"}
{"name":"goal 3","description":"This is another child goal","type":"goal"}
{"name":"goal 4","description":"This is another parent goal","subgoals":["goal5","goal6","goal7"],"type":"goal"}
{"name":"goal 5","description":"This is a child goal","type":"goal"}
{"name":"goal 6","description":"This is a child goal","type":"goal"}
{"name":"goal 7","description":"This is a child goal","type":"goal"}
```

You would then write a view that outputs each parent goal followed by its children:

```
function (doc, meta) 
{
  if (doc.type == "goal" && doc.subgoals)
  {
    emit([meta.id, 0], null);
        for(var idx in doc.subgoals)
        {
          emit([doc.subgoals[idx], 1], null);
        }    
  }
}
```

The output of this view is a set of rows, where each row contains a key consisting of the parent ID and a 0, followed by its children and a 1 (the 0 and 1 ensure that the rows are ordered correctly):

```
{"id":"goal1","key":["goal1",0],"value":null},
{"id":"goal1","key":["goal2",1],"value":null},
{"id":"goal1","key":["goal3",1],"value":null},
{"id":"goal4","key":["goal4",0],"value":null},
{"id":"goal4","key":["goal5",1],"value":null},
{"id":"goal4","key":["goal6",1],"value":null}
```

In the .NET SDK tutorial, I describe how to query a collated view (a Brewery and its beers).

[http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-net-1.2/collatedviews.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625223633/http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-net-1.2/collatedviews.html)

Comment: Yeah, I think a collated view seems to be preferable to requesting a document and then making a request for each related document from the DAL.

Could potentially make this a recursive function to retrieve n-levels of subgoals

Cheers John

Comment: Glad that helped.  Let me know if you need any assistance once you get going.